# WASAPI Event driven capture naudio

Tags: naudio

Is it possible to capture a line-in signal with NAudio in exclusive, event-driven mode?
If yes, is there an example available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WasapiCapture` class does not support event mode currently. As it happens, I just did a check-in to support exclusive mode though, which will be part of NAudio 1.7 when it is released shortly. If you need event-driven mode, then you could just take a copy of the `WasapiCapture` class and make the modifications yourself.

Comment: In a copy of WasapiCapture  I made the modifications:
audioClient.Initialize(AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, AudioClientStreamFlags.EventCallback,                requestedDuration,requestedDuration,this.waveFormat,Guid.Empty);

After client.Start() in DoRecording I get an error: HRESULT: 0x88890014 >> AUDCLNT_E_EVENTHANDLE_NOT_SET

Comment: In DoRecording I added
    var eventHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);  
    AudioClient.SetEventHandle(eventHandle.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle());  
and in the loop eventHandle.WaitOne() instead of Sleep().  

Now it works.

Comment: great, probably will try to get something similar into NAudio fairly soon. Need to make sure the duration and periodicity in Initialize are still correct for all four possible permutations of Shared/Exclusive and Event/Sleep

Comment: A good example in C++: [The mysterious WASAPI lock on Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allaboutwmsdks/archive/2013/09/06/on-windows-7-the-wasapi-release-of-the-capture-audio-client-will-lock-if-the-release-is-called-when-a-usb-audio-device-is-disconnected.aspx)